# Is there a difference between false (metastable) and local equilibria?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, equilibrium

Or is it permissible to use the terms interchangeably? If there is a difference, what is it?

Comment: I never met false  equilibrium  in thermodynamics. Could you provide more details about the context where you found such names?

Comment: It's a term that Pierre Duhem uses to talk about metastable states.

Comment: You'll want to quote the original source, ideally with a link, but, yeah, they sound the same.